# Unable to render map on html page using tom tom map

Tags: javascript, html, image, leaflet

1. First I register on the official website of tom tom map http://developer.tomtom.com/
2. Get a API key for MapKit and downlooad JavaScript SDK 2.1 from http://developer.tomtom.com/products/onlinenavigation/mapkit/Downloads
3. I got the API key on my mail.
4. In the downloaded folder of "JavaScript SDK 2.1" I edit the APIKEY in the file apikey.js. Like tomtom.apiKey = "3csxpg4dwd67bg9k8y3gzrzg";

This is the code in apikey.js

```
tomtom.apiKey = "3csxpg4dwd67bg9k8y3gzrzg";
```

This is my html code in map.html which i am trying to run on Mozilla browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>TomTom JavaScript SDK - Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/tomtom.map.min.css"         />
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet"     href="../css/tomtom.map.ie.min.css" /><![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/tomtom.map.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="apikey.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            // set the base image path used by tomtom.Marker
            tomtom.setImagePath("../images/");

            // create a basic map
            var map = new tomtom.Map({
                domNode: "map",

            });
        };
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" id="map"></div>
</body>
```

But the map is not rendering on my browser. And one thing to not that I done this work using mapbox API services.

Here is the output of Map using mapbox Services.
[I am attaching a image of output using leafletJs and mapbx API services.]

Can anybody tell me where i am commiting any mistakes or I should change the way to access tomtom map.  Please please help me. thanks a lot in advanced.

Comment: Mapkit or Mapbox? You need to be a bit clearer about exactly what you're trying to do, and where you're going wrong.

Comment: I am trying to draw map using MapKit (using tom tom). But not able to draw.